# Display Android Notification Bar with GCM and React Native

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, react-native, android-notifications

I'm using React Native and [this notification plugin](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to catch GCM notifications on Android. But while they're showing up fine in the Notifications Panel, I don't get the notification "banner" I was expecting. How do I make Android show notifications like this:

[image: desired notification display]

Thanks.

Comment: Got solution to this issue?

Comment: No. Haven't had time to look into it. I'll post an answer here if I figure it out.